# How to set y-axis tick label in matplot lib

Tags: matplotlib

My Y-aixs tick labels are showing strange behaviour.
By default Y-axis has maximum limit as read from file but I could not increase the label size.
So I have inserted

```
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=28)
```

After inserting this line the Y-axis goes to 15 and the minor tick label are at the interval of 2.5 and appears as flots (example, 1 is appearing as 1.0)

I have tried with below to make the Y-axis labels integer but could not.

```
ax1.set_yticklabels(tick_labels.astype(int))
```

I want to keep my Y-axis labels defaults but want to increase the label size.

I am getting below error

```
    ax1.set_yticklabels(tick_labels.astype(int))
NameError: name 'tick_labels' is not defined
```

Comment: What is `ax2`? Do you have two y-axis?

Comment: I have a (221) to (224) size plot and here ax2 represents 222 plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914462/matplotlib-how-to-force-integer-tick-labels/34880501)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# your code here

# For minor ticks
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# For major ticks
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. How to control interval of Y-axis?