# How to force AxesSubplot to use integer tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm struggling to correctly apply Integerlabels to the AxesSubplot Object. Somehow all the other popular solutions don't work. I presume this has to do with the nature of how Pandas plots vs how Matplotlib natively plots a dataframe.

When looking at the docs, there is a mention about preventing resolution adjustments by [using the optional parameter `x_compat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment) like so:

```py
df['A'].plot(x_compat=True)
```

However this only throws me an error and I also can't find this parameter in the [pandas 1.1.2 docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.htmlhttps://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

This is the code that produces the plot:

```py
def count_id(id_val):
    plot = df[df['ID']==id_val]['TRANSCRIPTION_STRING'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    plot.set_xticklabels(plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha ='right')
    print(type(plot))
```

[image]

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914462/matplotlib-how-to-force-integer-tick-labels) and it wasn't helpful for the following reasons:

- It uses `.gca()` which throws an error for my case.
- It's specifically using `matplotlib` instead of `pandas.plot`, which is the same under the hood, but hardly has very different documentation and isn't obvious to work for my case. More experienced users might differ.

It was a good suggestion and I see the similarities, but I very much tried to find it helpful before asking and it just wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

plot.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

`MaxNLocator` is the default ['locator'](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) for the ticks. You can also force some fixed multiples, e.g. `set_major_locator(MultipleLocater(1))`.

PS: The usual variable name for the return value of pandas `plot` functions is `ax`. This makes it clearer that the standard matplotlib functions can be used to customize the plots.

```
    ax = df[df['ID']==id_val]['TRANSCRIPTION_STRING'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    ax.set_xticklabels(plot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha ='right')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```