# How to round scientific notation formatted axis tick labels to integers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a histogram which has scientific notation of values along Y axis:

[image: Histograms showing the amount pixels for a certain brightness value]

The Channel B histogram has decimals along the Y axis. I want these numbers to be integers. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188757/matplotlib-specify-format-of-floats-for-tick-labels), but once `set_major_formatter` is applied, the scientific notation is ruined, and then I cannot get it back since `pyplot.ticklabel_format(axis = 'y', style = 'sci')` raises `AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter`. How can I prevent scientific notation from having decimals?

Comment: What if you define a list of integers to place ticks at, say `x`, and use `plt.yticks(x)` or `ax.set_yticks(x)`?

Comment: All the subplots are built in a single loop. I'd like this to be automated and not to depend on a given image for analysis

Comment: " I want these numbers to be integers... the scientific notation is ruined" I don't follow. Scientific notation inherently requires floating-point numbers.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel floating numbers with no decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34880501/14755500) offering [`MaxNLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator). It seems to work pretty fine if the amount of bins allows to keep ticks as integers. So for a simple plot it may go like this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
# Some code
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer = True, nbins = 3))
```

The same can be applied to `xaxis`.