# I want to convert all floats to integers(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 2]
plt.errorbar(x, y, c='red')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='red')
plt.tick_params(rotation = 45)
plt.title("Points")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

I don't want any float numbers so I just want 1,2,3

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34880501/7789963

Answer (score 0):

Use `xticks` and `yticks` to modify your the x and y tick labels

for example,

```
plt.xticks(range(1, 3))
plt.yticks(range(2, 4))
```

output:

[image]

Anyways, your data have very short range (range of 1-3). It gonna be weird if not using float number.

Comment: where did range(1,3) and range(3,5) come from? –

Comment: it's just an example. You can specify any number that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator). `MultipleLocator`, Ticks and range are a multiple of base; **either integer or float**.

> class matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=1.0)
>
> > Set a tick on each integer multiple of a base within the view interval.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 2]
plt.errorbar(x, y, c='red')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='red')
plt.tick_params(rotation = 45)
plt.title("Points")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to remove that unnecessary gap?

Comment: What do you mean by `unnecessary gap`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **xticks** and **yticks** to set the range of *x-* and *y-axes*; here is the full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 2]
plt.errorbar(x, y, c='red')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='red')
plt.tick_params(rotation = 45)
plt.title("Points")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

plt.xticks(range(1, 3))
plt.yticks(range(3, 4))
plt.show()
```

enjoy!

Comment: where did range(1,3) and range(3,5) come from?

Comment: This is to get the scale of x- and y-axis runs between(1, 2) and (3, 4) respectively, you could use different integers and run the code to see the difference between figures.