# Set steps on y-axis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I have the problem that I do not get the steps on the **y-axis** (score) changed. My representation currently looks like this:

[image]

However, since only whole numbers are possible in my evaluation, these 0.5 steps are rather meaningless in my representation. I would like to change these steps from 0.5 to 1.0. So that I get the steps `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]` instead of `[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, ...]`.

My code broken down to the most necessary and simplified looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# some calculations


x = np.arange(len(something))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, test1_means, width, label='Test 1')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, test2_means, width, label='Test 2')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Something to check')
ax.set_xticks(x, something)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

In addition, after research, I tried setting the variable `ax.set_yticks` or adjusting the `fig`. Unfortunately, these attempts did not work.

What am I doing wrong or is this a default setting of matplotlib at this point?

---

**Edit after comment:**

My calculations are prepared on the basis of Excel data. Here is a reproducible code snippet with the current values how the code might look like in the final effect:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stories = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
test1_means = [2, 3, 2, 3, 1]
test2_means = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

x = np.arange(len(stories))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, test1_means, width, label='Test 1')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, test2_means, width, label='Test 2')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Something')
ax.set_xticks(x, stories)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example without `something`, `test1_means`, `...` ?

Comment: Do you want to remove 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 or do you want to transform 0.5 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 1.5 -> 3, etc?

Comment: @Timeless added a reproducible code snippet below.

Comment: @Corralien You see the steps on the left side with the 0.5 steps. I want to change them into 1.0 steps. A transformation shouldn't be necessary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Axes.set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks). Add those lines right before the plot :

```
N = 1 # <- you can adjust the step here

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, max(test1_means + test2_means) + 1, N))
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34880501/1862861), you just need to do:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

# set y-axis to only show integer values
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would work for my case, but isn't there another approach to this? What would be the case in another use case if I want to display all steps of 2 on the y-axis? So for example [0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ...] - then this solution would not work anymore.