# Best way to plot 3D data over a large range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have some function  `f(x,y) --> z`

The range of `x` is small, typically ~0.1 -1

The range of `y` is large, typically 1e8 - 1e14

The output of the function `z` also has a large range, from ~ 1e25 - 1e45

**What is the best way to plot this function in Python?**

Clearly I need some kind of logarithmic axes, but log scaling 3d plots in matplotlib lib is an issue ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909794/plotting-mplot3d-axes3d-xyz-surface-plot-with-log-scale))

I have tried a colorbar plot, e.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1e8,1e14,500)
y = np.linspace(0.01,1,500)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = process(X,Y).T
im = plt.imshow(Z,cmap=cm.RdBu,norm=LogNorm())
im.set_interpolation('bilinear')
cb = fig.colorbar(im)
```

But the colours tend to 'wash out', e.g. the plot is mostly composed of just one colour and the x/y ticks go weird due to the normalisation which I have not found a way to fix.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a working code?

Comment: If you don't want to "wash out" data, use "nearest" as interpolation.