# 3D graph logging z axis (ISSUE209 RESOLVED)

Tags: logging, 3d, axis

I have created a 3D plot using csv data. I would like to log the z-axis however it appears that you can only change the labels, not the actual dimensions of the axis. Please see the script attached below:

```
enter code here

import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
import bbox
csvFileName = sys.argv[0]
csvData = []
with open('Ben*PAR_nh.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
 csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
 for csvRow in csvReader:
     csvData.append(csvRow)
csvData = np.array(csvData)
csvData = csvData.astype(float)
X, Y, Z = csvData[:,0], csvData[:,1], csvData[:,2]
#change vmin and vmax values for colorbar range
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cb = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75)
#cb = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75, vmin=0, 
vmax=800)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='red', marker='o')
fig.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.5)
ax.set_title("First-year sea ice PAR")
ax.set_xlabel("SZA")
ax.set_ylabel("Ice thickness")
ax.set_zlabel("µmol m$^{-2}$ $^{s-1}$")
ax.view_init(azim=70, elev=30)
image_format = 'png' # e.g .png, .svg, etc.
image_name = 'test.eps'
plt.show()
fig.savefig(image_name, format=image_format, dpi=1200)
```

**Thanks to Jamie's answer the plot now works with the Z axis now being logged - see below. The data range for the Z axis is from ~0.6 - 5e-07 resulting in the smallest values being difficult to see at this scale (0,1,4) - are there any suggestions for trying a different type of log?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU70X.png)**

```
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
import bbox

csvFileName = sys.argv[0]
csvData = []
with open('parvalues.dat', 'r') as csvfile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for csvRow in csvReader:
    csvData.append(csvRow)

csvData = np.array(csvData)
csvData = csvData.astype(float)
X, Y, Z = csvData[:,0], csvData[:,1], csvData[:,2]

#change vmin and vmax values for colorbar range
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cb = ax.plot_trisurf*(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75)

#cb = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75, 
vmin=0, vmax=800)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='red', marker='o')


fig.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.5)

ax.set_title("First-year sea ice PAR")
ax.set_xlabel("SZA")
ax.set_ylabel("Ice thickness")
ax.set_zlabel("µmol m$^{-2}$ $^{s-1}$")
ax.view_init(azim=70, elev=30)

image_format = 'png' # e.g .png, .svg, etc.
image_name = 'test.eps'
tight_layout()

plt.show()
fig.savefig(image_name, format=image_format, dpi=1200)
```

Comment: Please consider using more helpful / topical tags for your questions, for example in this case `python` and `matplotlib` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Confused as to what you mean by 'log the axes', but I've made a work around where you can plot the log of the data, with a log scale, which I think is what you want to do, though of coure I don't know the dimensions of your data as its not shown so used random integers; This is my first help out on stack so have mercy if its awful code, seems to work though

```
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
#import bbox
import random


#I created random data here as I don't know what your data is like
X = random.sample(range(0,100),50)
Y = random.sample(range(0,100),50)
Z = random.sample(range(0,1000000), 50)


#ORIGINAL PLOT YOUR WORK
#change vmin and vmax values for colorbar range
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection='3d')
cb = ax1.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75)
cb = ax1.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75, vmin=0, 
vmax=800)
ax1.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='red', marker='o')
fig.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.5)
ax1.set_title("First-year sea ice PAR")
ax1.set_xlabel("SZA")
ax1.set_ylabel("Ice thickness")
ax1.set_zlabel("µmol m$^{-2}$ $^{s-1}$")
ax1.view_init(azim=70, elev=30)
image_format = 'png' # e.g .png, .svg, etc.
image_name = 'test.eps'








### ISSUE SOLVING ###

### Create logZ data ####
logZ = np.log10(Z)


#Create the ticks you wish here, I assume orders of magnitude, so the (-2,2,1) here defines from 10^-2 to 10^5 in steps of orders of magnitude
zticks = [10**i for i in range(-2,6,1)]

#Log these ticks, as you want these on as the ticks on the graph in log form
logzticks = np.log10(zticks)


#Create tick labels based on the ticks themselves, these can be used if you want to label the actual data, but on a log scale, alternatively you can label the logged ticks ie
# a log axis ranging from -2 to 5 instead of 10^-2 to 10^5
def ticklabels(ticks):
    ticks_labels = []
    for i in ticks:
        ticks_labels.append(f'10^{np.log10(i)}')
    return ticks_labels

log_ztick_labels = ticklabels(zticks)


### NEW LOG PLOT ###
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection = '3d')

   
cb = ax2.plot_trisurf(X, Y, logZ, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75)
cb = ax2.plot_trisurf(X, Y, logZ, cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75, vmin=0, 
vmax=800)
ax2.scatter(X, Y, logZ, c='red', marker='o')
fig.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.5)
ax2.set_title("First-year sea ice PAR (LOGSCALE EDIT)")
ax2.set_xlabel("SZA")
ax2.set_ylabel("Ice thickness")
ax2.set_zlabel("µmol m$^{-2}$ $^{s-1}$")
#Change z ticks and labels to change the logs here
ax2.set_zticklabels(log_ztick_labels)
ax2.set_zticks(logzticks)
ax2.view_init(azim=70, elev=30)

plt.show()
```

[Resulting two graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5A3J.png)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be alot of known issues around 3D plots and log scales not playing nicely.. Matplotlib [Issue 209](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/209) discusses this with suggested work arounds. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909794/plotting-mplot3d-axes3d-xyz-surface-plot-with-log-scale) also looks similar to what your trying to do?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909794/plotting-mplot3d-axes3d-xyz-surface-plot-with-log-scale) the key seems to be plot the log data directly:

```py
ax.scatter(X, Y, np.log10(Z))
```

Then apply the following function to update the ticker formatting on `zaxis`:

```py
def log_tick_formatter(val, pos=None):
    """Reformat log ticks for display"""
    return f"$10^{{{int(val)}}}$"

ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(log_tick_formatter))
```

Example with your plot setup and some dummy data: [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0dcc.png) / [code example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dn2OXbvxEX5mQnnvjq6EhM-Hp6wN3r0h?usp=sharing)